# Can't increase scrollback buffer size in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760281/how-to-increase-scrollback-buffer-size-in-tmux) answer I tried increasing the buffer size using commands

```
set-option -g history-limit 10000
set -g history-limit 10000
```

but it does not work for me. I want to increase the buffer size of all the windows or at least the current window in tmux. I am opening the tmux session in Putty.

Note: I was trying to use the mouse scroll. I am able to scroll up using "prefix [" but not using the mouse

Comment: This works fine here. My tmux shows an orange bar at the top right when I enter control mode. This shows how far back into history I'm going (PgUp). You have to have filled your buffer some before you can go back, of course. What does your orange bar show after you've filled some screens worth?

Comment: I don't see any orange bar at the top. Strange.

Comment: Are you trying to change the limit for *existing* panes? There is no way to do that; `history-limit` only affects *new* panes.

Answer (score 9):

Some troubleshooting tools that helped me when I had this problem:

```
yes
```

to quickly fill up the scrollback

```
tmux new-session
```

to make sure I was getting a new session

```
tmux show-options -g
```

to see if tmux actually had the right setting.

In my case, I was unknowingly attaching to previous tmux sessions, that were created before I increased the `history-limit`.

Comment: Even after doing all the above (tmux new-session, ...), I had to logout out of *all* my existing tmux sessions, before the new history-limit took effect: "tmux a", exit all windows, "tmux a", exit windows, .. repeat until "tmux a" fails.

Comment: I exited all of my sessions and created a new ssh session to boot. The history limit  change still did not increase the scroll buffer, though tmux show-options -g  shows the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had some tmux processes running even though `tmux a` showed no attachable sessions. I manually killed every tmux process and after starting a new session new `history-limit` finally kicked in (check by `tmux show-options -g` to make sure).