# Linux tmux capture-pane to file

Tags: tmux

I would like to capture input/output from pane/session file.

just like `^A+L` in minicom

I tried `^b+: capture-pane` in tmux. but nothing work.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use pipe-pane. C-b : pipe-pane "cat >myfile"

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the current pane content to `stdout` with `tmux capture-pane -p -S -` and do whatever you want with a usual `stdout` pipe, e.g. pipe it to a `vim` buffer with `tmux capture-pane -p -S - | vim -`