# Tmux output truncated

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, tmux

I have just setup a long-running scrip on an Amazon EC2 Linux 2 instance.

All works fine, I created a new session, launched my script, disconnected from the sever and was able to log back in and see it still running - great.

Just one inconvenience, my script outputs around 150 lines of text on each iteration (runs every few hours).

After the first run, I can see the script printing as it should, but after the script finishes executing, the top ~90% seems to be lost and I can see the AWS default text from when I first logged in which is odd.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can see the full output from my script (and only my script) in a tmux window?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the scroll back buffer. In your `.tmux.conf` add something like,

```
set-option -g history-limit 10000
```

For some caveats, see answers to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18760281/).